# Need to Know how the ComponentWillMount came from React Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need to know how we are accessing the Lifecycle methods from React :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
 
 
class App extends Component{
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
}
 
componentWillMount() {
    //Theoretically we  tell that this `componentWillMount` is dereived/extended from 'Component' Class ie, in above like `class App extends Component`
}
 
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
}
};
```

Now the question is if you open the react source code file from here https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js

you do not find any abstract method like for componentWillMount
[image]

But if you open the react-dom file, https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js you can find the method, Question is Since we extent the Class with React.Component, we assume it is inside React library, not in ReactDOM, So not Clear How we are accessing the LifeCycle hooks from React library, which infact not available in that library
[image]

Comment: _Why_ do you "need to know" this about the React internals?

Comment: @AKX Because it's interesting? I think this is a very good question, understanding the internal workings of the libraries you use often has useful insights.

Comment: @Etheryte Sure, I get that, but that was the point of my question – whether it's just curiosity, or if there's some ill-advised "business case" that would hack around React internals.

Answer (score 0):

The magic seems to be in `react-reconciler`:

- You can find `typeof instance.componentDidMount === 'function'` instances in [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3f3b46c845333be5d8efcd9acb06e3ff57358189/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberClassComponent.new.js#L824-L830) that seem to mark that the React fiber is in a phase where it needs to have that function called.
- The function is then finally called [here in `ReactFiberCommitWork`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3f3b46c845333be5d8efcd9acb06e3ff57358189/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberCommitWork.new.js#L714-L717).

How those functions get called is more and more involved, and quite asynchronous too, likely.